# content flow between Ask Ubuntu, Ubuntuforums, Ubuntu Wikis

Tags: discussion

Is there any mechanism, official or informal, to flow information generated from Ask Ubuntu into other Ubuntu help sites, like Ubuntuforums or Ubuntu Wikis?

For example, a Q&A from Ask Ubuntu to be turned into a tutorial in another site.

Answer (score 3):

All the content is licensed under similar CC licences, so moving stuff around shouldn't be a problem, just make sure you're linking to the original pages for attribution and to make sure it can be updated.

Though, why copy around duplicate content instead of having it updated in one place?

Comment: I would like to know if more long-term content is already being moved around, other than wanting to do it myself. This is for me to understand what is the relationship between these sites, what are the ways in which they co-exist.

Comment: define "long-term" content please. As it stands, Ask Ubuntu is a good place for stuff.